# Calling LDAP using JAVA from Oracle Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, ldap

**Aim:** Using a Oracle Procedure/Function to execute a Java Code to connect LDAP, fetch details from it and generate an excel file with these details.

**Progress so far:**

Presently, I have been successful in

1) Calling a java code from oracle using external java libraries imported in oracle to generate a hard coded excel file on the server.

2) Executing a java code separately to connect LDAP, fetch details and generate an excel.

But when trying to call the java code from a procedure to connect LDAP, fetch details and generate Excel, the code is executing successfully and generating an Excel file but **THIS EXCEL FILE IS BLANK**.

Also, the following error message is coming,
**error when trying to create the context**

Following is the sample code

1) **LOADING EXTERNAL JARS**

```
loadjava -r -v -u  username/password  -s -g PUBLIC /oracle/awr/poi-3.7.jar
```

2) **PACKAGE AND PACKAGE BODY**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FetchADDetails AS 
FUNCTION callGenerateReport(p1 IN varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2; 
END FetchADDetails;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY FetchADDetails AS 
FUNCTION callGenerateReport(p1 IN varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'FetchADDetails.callGenerateReport(java.lang.String) 
return java.lang.String'; 
END FetchADDetails;
/
```

3) **COMPILING JAVA CLASS**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "FetchADDetails" AS
public class FetchADDetails
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(callGenerateReport(null));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> fetchDetails(String userid, String password)
    {
        ArrayList<String> fetchedData=new ArrayList<String>();
        String url = "ldap://IP_ADDRESS";
        Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
        String securityPrincipal = userid+"@DOMAIN_NAME";
        String securityCredentials = password;
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityCredentials);

        try
        {           
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            try
            {
                SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
                String[] returnedAtts = {"sn", "givenName", "displayname", "mail", "telephonenumber"};
                searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
                searchCtls.setSearchScope(2);

                String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=" + userid + "@DOMAIN_NAME)))";
                String searchBase = "DC=corp,DC=DOMAIN_NAME,DC=com";

                NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
                //System.out.println(answer.next().getAttributes());
                if (answer.hasMore())
                {
                    Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
                    String fullName=(String) attrs.get("displayname").get();
                    String eMail;
                    String phoneNumber;
                    if(attrs.get("mail")==null)
                    {
                        eMail="NA";
                    }
                    else
                    {eMail=(String) attrs.get("mail").get();}
                    if(attrs.get("telephonenumber")==null)
                    {phoneNumber="NA";}
                    else
                    {phoneNumber=(String) attrs.get("telephonenumber").get();}
                    //System.out.println(userid.toUpperCase()+","+fullName+","+eMail+","+phoneNumber);                  
                    fetchedData.add(userid.toUpperCase()+","+fullName+","+eMail+","+phoneNumber);
                }
                else
                {throw new Exception("Invalid User");}

            } 
            catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
            ctx.close();
        }
        catch (AuthenticationNotSupportedException ex){System.out.println("The authentication is not supported by the server");}
        catch (AuthenticationException ex){System.out.println("incorrect password or username");}
        catch (NamingException ex){System.out.println("error when trying to create the context");}
        return fetchedData;
    }

    public static String callGenerateReport(String text)
    {
        ArrayList<String> adDetailsList=new ArrayList<String>();
        adDetailsList=fetchDetails(<username>,<password>);
        generateReport(adDetailsList);
        return "Successful!!!";
    }

    public static void generateReport(ArrayList<String> adDetailsList)
    {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet activeDirectoryDetails = workbook.createSheet("Active Directory Details");        

        **CODE GOES HERE**

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(new File("MyFilePath/Test.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();             
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

4) **CALL FUNCTION**

```
begin
declare
result varchar2(4000);
begin
dbms_output.ENABLE;
result := FetchADDetails.callGenerateReport('My First Excel');
dbms_output.put_line(substr('poi result='||result,1,250));
exception
when OTHERS then
dbms_output.put_line(substr('poi error='||SQLERRM,1,250));
end;
end;
```

This is running successfully but generating a blank excel file. Please help me in resolving the issue and generating an excel file with details.

Comment: When you catch an exception, print the error message that comes with the exception. Not something you made up yourself. All you have here is 'error when trying to create the context'. *What* error? Only you can tell us.

Comment: To get the root cause change the Naming exception line to catch (NamingException ex){System.out.println("error when trying to create the context"+ ex.getCause());}

Comment: @psaraj No. He should print the entire stack trace. You're assuming there is a nested exception. There may not be. We don't know. It's up to the OP to tell us. Making assumptions is how he got into this mess.